# Problems when trying to create a QR code encoder

Tags: python

I'm trying to create an encoder for QR Code so when I click to start it gives an error in this part (the part that is different from the rest and the part that is giving error)

```py
import qrcode

link_text = str(input('Enter the website/text you want: '))

>   filename = str(input('Enter the filename: ')) image_type = str(input('Enter which image type: \n1 --> For "png" files \n2 --> For "jpeg" files \n3 --> For "jpg" files\n--> ') )
>   image_format = "" if image_type == 1:
>   image_format = "png" elif image_type == 2:
>   image_format = "jpeg" elif image_type == 3:
>   image_format = "jpg"

img = qrcode.make(link_text)
type(img)
img.save(f"{file_name}.{image_format}")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`image_type` is a `str`, which you're trying compare with `int` literals (i.e. `1`, `2`, `3`). You can't compare a `str` with an `int`; you'll always get `False`. Either cast `image_type` into an `int` or, better yet, scrap the `image_type` variable, allow the user to directly enter "PNG", "JPEG", or "JPG", and just use that as the extension.